# Organizing datevec in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to vectorize my Matlab code, but I'm running into trouble trying to organize my datevec array to show the same day for every year.

For instance, I have a datevec array for june:

```
1900    6    1    0    0    0
1900    6    2    0    0    0 
1900    6    3    0    0    0
... 
2013    6   30    0    0    0
```

which contains every single day in June from 1900-2013. Is there anyway to organize a datevec array by year, while maintaining correct dates? My end result would be look like below:

```
1900   6     1    0    0    0
1901   6     1    0    0    0
1902   6     1    0    0    0 
...
2013   6     30   0    0    0
```

I tried using

```
june(sort(june(:,3)),:)
```

which returns the dates in the correct organized fashion, however the year columns are incorrect.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still working out how to do it without a loop, but this (I think) answers the question:

```
[~,idx] = sort(june(:,3));
sorted_table = zeros(size(june));

for ii = 1:length(idx)
    sorted_table(ii,:) = june(idx(ii),:);
end
```

EDIT: Just discovered the built-in [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html):

```
sorted_table = sortrows(june,[3 1])
```

Sorts by column 3 and then column 1

Comment: I'm continuously surprised how I can gloss over these functions. Thank you!